# How to do PGP for web applications

Tags: web-applications, cryptography, pgp

I have a text processing service. At this moment it is not secured with any kind of cryptography (except SSL). Since it collects a big amount of user's data I need to implement some security trade-off decision. This is what I think this [asymmetric] simplified cryptography may look like.

1. Separate database layer. Should only store encrypted private data and nothing more (no private keys, no public keys).
2. Microservices. My service is divided by ~10 mostly independent microservices. When the user stores data, it's beeing encrypted with a public key of a current microservice instance and is stored at the databse layer. Microservice should not store its private key as a plain text. Private key should be decrypted by demand (by user http request) with a key requested from a key server by a runtime token.
3. Key storage. It keeps the microservice's private key decryption key and should be accessible only within the private network. When microservice (2) starts up, it authenticates with verified runtime token in a key storage with manual approvement and gains access to private key decryption key. These key attempts are logged every time.

Can these approaches help me to keep user's private data mostly safe?

Comment: This is all fine, but its effective security completely depends on the key storage's security. Quite frankly I do not see any real difference between using such a storage microservice and storing the key on disk _if it is stored at all_. So why all the effort?

Comment: This would make sense in my eyes if the private key were not stored at all, but only provided on-the-fly per request. That would mean a break in to your systems would _not_ allow to decrypt the data which certainly _would_ be possible with your approach.